# Electrical engineering version of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

I think we need another incarnation of Stack Overflow for electrical engineering questions. I just answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240671/what-is-the-difference-of-a-relay-controller-verses-a-micro-controller/) on Stack Overflow which probably should have been marked as Not Programming Related, yet it's one of a family of questions that need a good community to ask and also are tangentially related to programming. I propose that this new site, if created, be for questions about circuit design, selection of components, and things of that nature. Not "how do I replace my iPod's battery". Should we go forward?

I even thought up a potential name for it... Spark Overflow.

Comment: SparkOverflow is dumb. Go with ShortCircuit instead.

Comment: welbog, that is a better name :)  good thinking

Comment: IJustShockedMyself.com

Comment: iJustBurnedMyselfOnASolderingIron.com

Comment: IEEE-EE-EEK.com

Comment: 0118999881999119725-3.com <-- bonus points for whoever can figure that out without googling.

Comment: I like the movie "Short Circuit".

Comment: everyone below so far has made very valid points... this is something better served by Stack Exchange.  I hadn't even considered that as an option... silly me.  Thanks for all the ideas though.

Comment: A circuit site would be great. Where do you draw the line between analog and digital, though? I notice my kid's electronic experiments kit comes with three audio ICs. And I have a lot more dsp questions than I have analog questions. A combined analog circuit/dsp site would be ideal for me.

Comment: By the way, how _do_ I replace my iPod's battery?

Comment: I wouldn't draw a line between analog and digital... on my hypothetical site, they'd both be welcome.  especially since so many concerns cross the boundary between the two, it doesn't make sense to me to separate them.

Comment: @TheTXI: Now I'll have that tune in my head all day! FIRE-exclamation mark. FIRE-exclamation mark. HELP ME-exclamation mark. Looking forward to hearing from you...

Comment: MagicBlueSmoke.com

http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/55/can-you-suggest-a-better-title-for-this-website

Comment: @Rubén don't flood. Five edits per day are just enough for old posts as part of tag removal. Thanks. Flooding the homepage with old posts is bad, even when the goal is good so please, don't do that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We have one now.

[Electronics Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

It needs a lot more members to be successful, so go ahead and register yourself!

Answer (score 6):

http://www.stackexchange.com

Other than that, I really don't think we need to keep expanding this trilogy. I think Jeff & the Team honestly need to concentrate on the development of their system instead of trying to spawn as many instances of it as possible.

Comment: I agree. Although all of these other sites sound like Good ideas, we need to improve the features of the current site and then let other people spawn their own sites.

Answer (score 2):

An electrical engineering SO would be great.  We'd need something to do the EE symbols (latex?).

Comment: You also would have to make sure that you get moderators who are experienced enough in the field to know what belongs and what doesn't. I am not sure if Jeff and the current team or any of the current moderators (I know I personally wouldn't be) are qualified to make those designations. It doesn't make sense to open up sites where the site owners are not knowledgeable of the subject they are creating a site for.

Comment: Very good point, it definitely should be moderated by those who would know what's up.

Answer (score 1):

When Stack Exchange opens, go ahead and make one.